# best way to use self join associations for occurrences of an event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, getter, self-join

I have this working rails Event model which has some self join associations to find any occurrences of an event. It has some custom getters which returns the main_events title and description on any occurrence.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this in rails? and Should the main event be included inside the occurrences as well?

For example when iterating through a specific events occurrences, the main event date had ought to be displayed too.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

    # linked_event:integer name:string description:text date:datetime

  has_many :occurrences, :class_name => "Event", :foreign_key => "linked_event"
  belongs_to :main_event, :class_name => "Event", :foreign_key => "linked_event"

  def name
    return Event.find(self[:linked_event]).name if self[:linked_event]
    return self[:name]
  end

  def description
    return Event.find(self[:linked_event]).description if self[:linked_event]
    return self[:description]
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd split the two classes up; have an `Event` model which carries the name and description, plus an `Occurrence` model with the datetime. Then `Event has_many :occurrences`

When you get an `Event`, you check to see if it already exists in the DB; if so you just create a new `Occurrence`, otherwise you create the `Event` and a single `Occurrence`.

Something like this (adjust so that it works - I haven't tested it!):

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  # name:string description:text
  has_many :occurrences
end

class Occurrence < ActiveRecord::Base
  # event_id:integer date:datetime
  belongs_to :event
end

def add_event(params)
  ev = Event.find_by_name(params[:name])
  if !ev
    ev = Event.create!(params)
  end

  Occurrence.create!(:event => ev, :date => Time.now)
end
```